# Element will be remove by RootPanel.get(String id) after close a window in GXT

Tags: html, dom, gwt, getelementbyid, gxt

I have a gwt project with GXT framework, and have an embed tag in my project.html as below

```
<embed type="application/nptta" width=100% height=100% id="testId"></embed>
```

There has a formPanel will using `RootPanel.get("testId");` and add into formPanel.

```
formPanel.add(RootPanel.get("testId"));
```

At the very first time when page has loaded. It works fine. Element is there and panel has show up the embedded. But when I has closed the window which contains the form and open it again, the RootPanel.get("testId"); will become null, I guess is that has GWT GC remove the embedded? Did there any way to avoid this situation?

Have tried using `DOM.getElemenetById("testId");`, but doesn't know how to convert the returned `Element` into `Widget` and add into a `FormPanel`

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Did my answer help? If yes you should accept it so the thread can be considered closed. If not please provide feedback so I can update my answer. If you've already found another solution to your problem then please post that and accept it, so others can benefit too.

Comment: I have found that the element will be null, not only after the window has closed and also collapsed. Due to those operations will notify hide() of components which are on the window, and my embed object will be GC I guess. I currently used that way is to set visibility of style attribute to hidden, to achieve the function of close and also collapse of window. This is only a workaround and I don't think it is a solution of this problem.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
Element element = DOM.getElemenetById("testId");
Widget widget = (Widget)DOM.getEventListener(element);
```

Comment: Note that this will only work if the root element of the widget is that element. If the `<embed>` is nested inside the widget, this will not work - you must walk up element.getParent() to find a non-null widget.

Comment: Hi alkis, thanks for your answer and sorry for the late reply. I have got some time back to the branch and tried your suggestion. However, the widget will become an undefined object in js, but the element is for sure existed.